# jQuery: difference between filter and find

Tags: jquery

what is difference between filter and find function in jquery ??
filter function and find function do the same job in jquery according to the my experience.
Who can tell the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [find method](http://api.jquery.com/find/), retrieves a group of elements that match a given selector.

```
var items = $( "#group" ).find( "#.item" ); // finds items within the group
```

The [filter method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)  can then reduce the already matched elements to a smaller collection with another selector.

```
var special_items = items.filter( ".special" ); // only extract "special" items
```

---

Essentially, they can both do the same job. You could simulate the find function with filter by simply passing every element to the filter function. This doesn't make much sense but it might help to know when trying to understand the difference between them.

The following two commands will yield the same number of elements:

```
$( document ).find( "a" ).length

$( "*" ).filter( "a" ).length
```

With regard to the performance consideration I would say where ever you can, limit the number of elements that need to be scanned.

Answer (score 2):

`.filter()` will take a jQuery collection (list of elements) and will filter it to give a subset in a new collection.

`.find()` finds descendants of an element that match the passed selector.